# Selenium WebDriver test for Slack

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver

I submitted this script as part of a interview process. It was rejected and no reasons were given. I'm wondering what parts of my script were unacceptable. The script works, and satisfies the question, but I must be doing things very wrong.

> Use Selenium, Watir, Capybara, or similar to automate the following
>   user workflow:
>
> - Send a message to Slack by entering text in the box at the bottom of    the  - - client
> - Your message will appear in the current channel.
> - When you hover over the message, you'll see a star.
> - Click the star.
> - There is a search field on the upper right.
> - Enter the string has:star in this field and submit it.
> - Verify that your message appears in the search results.
> - Click the star icon on the upper right.
> - Verify that your message appears in this list.

```
// Setup test conditions and global resources.
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
var query = 'has:star';
var dataTs = -1;
var messageFoundInSearchResults = false;
var messageFoundInStarResults = false;
var errors = [];
var messageStarredTime = -1;

// Code used to login and navigate to a channel. Used to test this test. Commented out because exercise did not request
// this step.
/*
var generalUrl = 'https://yourproject.slack.com/messages/yourchannel/';
var email = 'your@email.com';
var password = 'yourpassword';
driver.get(generalUrl);
driver.findElement(By.id('email')).sendKeys(email);
driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.id('signin_btn')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
    "use strict";
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.className('ts_icon_side_panel'));
});
*/

// Enter message
driver.findElements(By.id('message-input')).then(function(elems) {

    "use strict";
    var sentTime = -1;
    var checkTime = -1;
    var timeDiff = -1;
    var timeout = 5000;
    var message = new Date().getTime();
    var messageReceived = false;

    if (elems.length > 0) {

        driver.findElement(By.id('message-input')).sendKeys(message + webdriver.Key.RETURN);
        sentTime = new Date().getTime();

        // Wait for new message to appear within timeout time, then get data timestamp.
        (function checkMessageSent() {

            driver.sleep(1000);
            checkTime = new Date().getTime();
            timeDiff = checkTime - sentTime;

            // For each message on the page, compare the messages text with the sent text.
            driver.findElements(By.css('ts-message')).then(function(elems) {
                elems.forEach(function(msg) {
                    msg.getText().then(function(text) {

                        // If the message text contains the sent text, then the message has been identified and the
                        // timestamp id is stored.
                        if (text.indexOf(message) > -1) {
                            messageReceived = true;
                            msg.getAttribute('data-ts').then(function(ts) {
                                dataTs = ts;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (messageReceived === false && timeDiff < timeout) {
                    checkMessageSent();
                } else if (messageReceived === false && timeDiff >= timeout) {
                    errors.push(Date() + ': Sent message not found.');
                }
            });
        }());
    } else {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find message-input');
    }
});

// Find message and click it's star using the timestamp id.
driver.findElements(By.css('ts-message')).then(function(elems) {

    "use strict";

    // For each message on page, compare timestamp id to find the correct message.
    elems.forEach(function(msg) {
        msg.getAttribute('data-ts').then(function(id) {
            if (id == dataTs) {

                // Hover over message
                driver.actions().mouseMove(msg).perform();

                // Find all star buttons for the message.
                driver.findElements(By.css('button[data-msg-id="' + dataTs + '"]')).then(function(btns) {

                    // Click the star button which is visible.
                    btns.forEach(function(btn) {
                        btn.isDisplayed().then(function(val) {
                            if (val === true) {
                                btn.click();

                                // Store the time the message was starred for use in the "has:star" search timeout.
                                messageStarredTime = new Date().getTime();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    if (btns.length === 0) {
                        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find any stars');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    if (elems.length === 0) {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find any ts-message');
    }
});

// Execute search until message is found or timeout reached.
driver.findElements(By.id('search_terms')).then(function(elems) {

    "use strict";
    var searchTime = -1;
    var timeDiff = -1;
    var maxWaitTime = 30000;
    var searchSleepTime = 5000;
    var searchPending = true;

    if (elems.length > 0) {

        // Focus on search bar
        driver.findElement(By.id('search_terms')).click();

        // Enter search query and search with Return key.
        driver.findElement(By.id('search_terms')).sendKeys(query + webdriver.Key.RETURN);

        // Pause for search results to appear.
        driver.wait(function() {
            return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.className('flex_content_scroller'));
        }, maxWaitTime);
    } else {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find search_terms');
    }

    // Check search results for message in recursive function.
    (function checkSearchResults() {

        // Get current time for timeout comparison.
        searchTime = new Date().getTime();
        timeDiff = searchTime - messageStarredTime;

        // Get all message results
        driver.findElements(By.className('search_message_result null_transform ')).then(function(msgs) {

            // Compare each id with the stored id.
            msgs.forEach(function(msg) {
                msg.getAttribute('data-ts').then(function(msgTs) {

                    // If the timestamp ID's match then the message is found.
                    if (msgTs == dataTs) {
                        messageFoundInSearchResults = true;
                    }
                });
            });

            // If message has not been found and timeout has not been reached re-execute search after delay
            if (messageFoundInSearchResults === false && timeDiff < maxWaitTime) {
                driver.sleep(searchSleepTime);
                driver.findElement(By.id('search_terms')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.RETURN);
                checkSearchResults();
            }
        });
    }());

    // Wait for the last search to complete.
    driver.wait(function(){
        driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.id('search_spinner')).then(function(isPresent){
            searchPending = isPresent;
        });
        if (searchPending === false) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});


// Click star icon and wait for results to load
driver.findElements(By.id('stars_toggle')).then(function(elems) {

    "use strict";
    var checkTime = -1;
    var starClickTime = -1;
    var timeDiff = -1;
    var waitTime = 3000;

    if (elems.length > 0) {
        driver.findElement(By.id('stars_toggle')).click();
        starClickTime = new Date().getTime();

        // Wait for results to load by checking if any message items are present in the results list, with timeout.
        (function checkStarredResults() {
            checkTime = new Date().getTime();
            timeDiff = checkTime - starClickTime;
            driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.className('message feature_fix_files   standalone  for_star_display' +
                '   first       ')).then(function(result) {
                if (result === false && timeDiff < waitTime) {
                    checkStarredResults();
                }
            });
        }());
    } else {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find stars_toggle');
    }
});



// Check list for message
driver.findElements(By.className('message feature_fix_files   standalone  for_star_display   ' +
    'first       ')).then(function(elems) {

    "use strict";

    elems.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.getAttribute('data-ts').then(function(elemTs) {

            // If the timestamp ID's match then the message is found.
            if (elemTs == dataTs) {
                messageFoundInStarResults = true;
                logErrors();
            }
        });
    });
    if (elems.length === 0) {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Cannot find any message feature_fix_files   standalone  for_star_display   first       ');
        logErrors();
    }
});

// Log and output test results.
var logErrors = function() {

    "use strict";

    // Log error if the message was not found in search results.
    if (messageFoundInSearchResults === false) {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Message not found in search results.');
    }

    // Log error if the message was not found in Star list.
    if (messageFoundInStarResults === false) {
        errors.push(Date() + ': Message not found in star results.');
    }

    // Output test result to console.
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        console.log('Test failed with ' + errors.length + ' errors:');
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Test passed with ' + errors.length + ' errors.');
    }
};

// Stop the test
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with javascript but there are few statements which raise red flag for me -

```
driver.findElement/s(By.***
```

having a method to get element/s and not repeat the entire statement again and again makes it more comprehensible

```
driver.sleep(1000);
```

Instead of sleep use explicit wait